# Як називається форма продажу сипких речей?

Tags: словосполучення

Питання стосується не форм гуртового/роздрібного продажу, а більш дрібних ситуацій, штибу купівлі товару у крамниці.

Наприклад, є умовний горох. Він продається фасованим у якісь пластикові упаковки фіксованої ємності, або просто стоїть мішок і можна собі відміряти довільну кількість. Чи є якесь слово(сполучення), яке описує другу форму?

Російською знаю варіант "на рассып" (див., наприклад, [тут](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/27268994)), але СУМ для слова "[розсип](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozsyp)" прикладу вживання у потрібному мені контексті не містить.

Answer (score 12):

Схоже, мається на увазi *насипом* (рос. *насыпью*) - [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nasypom) дає визначення:

> У насипаному вигляді, без тари.

Comment: Можна ще додати значення з [r2u](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E&scope=all&highlight=on)

Answer (score 7):

**НА́ТРУСОМ**

У словнику Грінченка:

> **На́трусом**, *нар.* О мѣряніи сыпучихъ тѣлъ: не набивая, не натискивая сверху, а довольствуясь тѣмъ, сколько войдетъ при простомъ насыпаніи. *Натрусом міряти овес, жито*. [[1](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC&scope=all&dicts=12&highlight=on)]

У словнику Ніковського:

> **На́трусом**, *нар.* – насыпая, в насыпку. [[2](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC&scope=all&dicts=8&highlight=on)]

Answer (score 3):

Російською такий продаж зветься «на развес», [українською](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) це буде «на вагу».

Comment: на вагу і м'ясо можна продавати, а тут саме про сипкі матеріали.